# Annoying NUL block in socket buffer

Tags: c++, string, sockets, null, buffer

im currently trying to write a c++ code on a mac to download a larger file from a website (~1GB). I think i have an error somewhere where i convert the socket buffer to a string, cause my resulting file (movie file) has some small blocks of nul chars spread through the whole file, and i need to somehow delete them from the string optained by the socket buffer.

This is the part which handles the http connection and the part which saves the date to the file. Some Parts may not be in this example like error handling or the complete socket building.

```
//I have error handling in here but stripped out from this example
char buffer[512];
portno = atoi("8080");
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
server = gethostbyname(address);

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
      (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
      server->h_length);

serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

bzero(buffer,512);
header.copy(buffer,512);

n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));

std::string str_buff;

while((n = read(sockfd,buffer,511)) > 0){

    std::string temp(buffer,511);
    //Is this the error^^^^^^^^^?

    write_chunk_to_file(temp);
    //cut



void write_chunk_to_file(std::string chunk){
   write.open(path+fname, std::ios::out | std::ios::app);

   write << remove_header(chunk);

   write.close();
   //cut




std::string remove_header(std::string chunk){

   if(chunk.find("")){
       chunk = chunk.substr(chunk.find(""),chunk.length());
   }

   return chunk;

}
```

When i compare the file my code downloads with the file wget downloads, i have some smaller blocks only consisting of NUL chars in my file and some extra bytes seem to exist also in my file.

Does anyone has a clue?

Comment: Think about it for a moment - what do you currently do if `read` only reads 200 bytes in one call?

Comment: @immibis - I'm guessing 'write 200 bytes to the file, followed by gunge, so that small blocks of nul chars and some extra bytes are spread through the whole file'.

Comment: @MartinJames *I* know what the program does, I just wanted to give the asker a chance to figure it out themselves first.

Comment: *facepalm okay i'll post if i have solved it..

Comment: @immibis lol, sorry:(

Comment: The simple answer is not to convert it to a string at all. You have the bytes, you have the length, just write it directly to the file. And the conceot of opening and closing the file before writing each chunk has knobs on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the line you indicated is an error:

```
std::string temp(buffer,511);
//Is this the error^^^^^^^^^?
```

`read()` returns how many bytes were actually read into the buffer.  You need to take that into account:

```
std::string temp(buffer,n);
```

Also, you are reading raw data, so `remove_header()` does not belong in `write_chunk_to_file()`. The buffer may contain portions of data for multiple headers and/or the body at the same time.  You need to implement a proper HTTP parser so you can detect where each header ends, where the body begins, where the body ends, and how the body is encoded. Then you can write just the body data to your file.

This code is not even remotely close to reading an HTTP response correctly. You need to implement logic more like this (I leave it as an exercise for you to implement it in C++):

```
send request
while true:
    read line
    if not successful:
        throw error
    if line is blank:
        break while loop
    add line to headers list
parse headers list
if response can contain message body:
    if HTTP version is 1.1+, and Transfer-Encoding header is present and not "identity":
        while true:
            read line, extract delimited ASCII hexadecimal for the chunk size
            if not successful:
                throw error
             if chunk size is 0:
                break while loop
             read chunk size number of bytes
        while true:
            read line
            if not successful:
                throw error
            if line is blank:
                break while loop
            add line to headers list, replace existing header if needed
        parse headers list again
    else if Content-Length header is specified:
        read Content-Length number of bytes
    else if Content-Type header is "multipart/byteranges":
        read and parse MIME-encoded chunks until terminating MIME boundary is reached
    else:
        read until connection is closed
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay got it now, changing the following line solved it:

```
std::string temp(buffer,511);
//changed to:
std::string temp(buffer,n);
```

I really got "more" then possible when copying 511 bytes, i needed only to copy n bytes read by read() from socket, thanks for the hint guys :D